# Derivative with a sum

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am going crazy over a relatively simple question. I want to find the derivative with respect to $\theta$ of

$\frac{1}{\theta} \sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_{i} - \text{log} \theta)$

Using the product rule I find this to be

$-\frac{1}{\theta^2}  \sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_{i} - \text{log} \theta) - \frac{1}{\theta^2}$

However, in my lecture notes it says

$-\frac{1}{\theta^2} (y_{i} - \text{log} \theta) - \frac{1}{\theta^2}$

Surely this cannot be correct?

EDIT: I added the derivation from the slides below. My thought it that there is a summation sign missing in part (b). Essentially I want to differentiate the part after "The FOC reads..."

[image]

Comment: The "lecture notes" expression looks like a vector, while your expression looks like a  scalar (which by your description it should be). Missing some details maybe?

Comment: I added my actual notes to clarify. In the beginning of the slides it says lets $y = (y_{1},...,y_{n})$. But if that is the case then surely there should be no $i$ subscript in the derivative?

Answer (score 0):

Your lecture notes expression tells you the term  by term derivative,

in any case, in your expression you have the sum of $\frac{-1}{\theta^2}$, which is $\frac{-n}{\theta^2}$

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you clarify what you mean by "term by term derivative"?

Comment: The derivative of the $n$th term of the sum